# How to close easyui dialog when click outside?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-easyui

In my project, I use easyui dialog.

I choose easyui-linkbutton to open dialog successfully.

Because it has no title, I want to close this dialog when clicking outside.

I don't know how to define.

Here is my js code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{ 
   $('#dlg').window('close');
});
</script>
```

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="easyui-panel" style="padding:5px;">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton" onclick="$('#dlg').dialog('open')" data-options="plain:true,iconCls:'icon-newfile'">addNewFile</a>
 </div>

<div  id="dlg" class="easyui-dialog"  title=""  data-options="iconCls:'icon-save'" style="width:88px;height:260px;top:160px;left:176px;padding:10px">
<label style="cursor:pointer">one</label><br />
<label style="cursor:pointer">two</label><br />
<label style="cursor:pointer">three</label>
</div>
```

Who can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one also and share the information if not work.write this code on document load.

```
$(document).mousedown(function(e) {
                    var clicked = $(e.target);                 
                    if (clicked.is('#dlg') || clicked.parents().is('.ui-widget-content') || clicked.is('.ui-dialog')) {                     
                        return;
                    } else { 
                        $('#dlg').dialog("close");
                    }
                });
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try once may this help.

```
$('#dlg' ).bind('clickoutside',function(){
    $('#dlg' ).dialog('close');
});
```

Comment: it display nothing. I use easyui, not jquery ui.

Comment: I share another answer check this one.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#dlg' ).dialog({
    clickOutside:true,
});
```

I have tested, it works fail.